# plan.cache: no matching files, unable to attach Terraform report to the MR

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I have following plan stage in my GitLab CI, which I took from [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml) but unlike `gitlab-terraform`, `terraform v1.1.0` doesn't have any option of `plan-json`, so I am trying to reproduce the same with the following. Aim is attached the plan changes as report in GitLab merge requests.

```
plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out=plan.json 
    - terraform show -json plan.json
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/plan.json
```

However, in MR all I see is  `1 Terraform report failed to generate` and in the complete job log I see following:

```
plan.cache: no matching files 
12ERROR: No files to upload
```

My question is, what is the difference between `artifacts:path` and the path given under `artifacts:reports:terraform`?

And, where can I find/generate `plan.cache`?

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v1.1.0
```

Comment: Because artifacts are only allowed to be in the workspace, I'd recommend setting the `TF_ROOT` variable explicitly in the job `variables:` key to a location within the workspace (ie. relative to `$CI_PROJECT_DIR`) as described in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html#get-started-using-gitlab-ci). Can you try that and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: as @sytech said you have to set TF_DIR/TF_ROOT and for example form my side I set my artifact like: terraform: ${TF_DIR}/$PLAN_JSON